# bias vs overfitting & variance vs underfitting

Tags: variance, bias, overfitting

In the very beginning of a video made by Andrew Ng (Associate professor at Standford), it is said that "the learning curves can help to diagnose whether a model is suffering from a bias, a variance problem or a **bit of both**"

My question is concerning the addition of the "bit of both" to the sentence above: How can an algorithm have both a variance and a bias problem at the same time?

you can find below the reference video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4XluwGYPaA&t=106s

Comment: easy imagine target is linear function of x and y and you fit it with cubic polynomial in x.  (or it is sin(x) and you fit it with (fixed order) polynomial... then no matter how much data it will never get the true function, and yet for any fixed data set with noise you will have overfitting with large enough polynomial

Comment: What I understood from your comment is that you will get overfitting by making your model too complex using, for example, a cubic polynomial instead of linear function. But this doesn't explain how you can get both a variance and a bias problem at the same time

Comment: If you fit a polynomial in 1 variable x,  but your true function depends on two variables x and y then you will have bias.